# Counting mechanism of Capital S in split function in Java

Tags: java, split

Whenever I write \\S (caps S) ,  then I get output 13,
Can anyone tell me how this count 13, I mean why it just remove the last word?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String Text = area.getText();
    String words[]=Text.split("\\S");
    l1.setText("Words : "+words.length);
    l2.setText("Character : "+Text.length());
}
```

I use ActionListener for a AWT program,

This code has the counting for words and characters,
But I just want to know why it shows 13 words, I mean, \\S split the words, but why it do not count the last word, and just count the all character without the last word?

Comment: Try printing the "words" that you get. I think you would be surprised. Hint: put some line-end markers so that you can actually see anything.

Comment: I believe this is because after the word `India` it no longer sees any further values that won't become a delimiter (ie. it doesn't see any more whitespace in this case) so it does not continue through the final word. You can test this by adding another whitespace character after `India` where it will then continue through to that whitespace character.

Comment: @TimHunter Yeah , if I add more words then it counting till before last word. I just tested that.. Thank you so much

Comment: The use of AWT is irrelevant to the substance of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use non-whitespace delimiter, I recommend flipping it to use whitespace as the delimiter then doing a sum on the lengths of each word:

```
int totalNonWhitespaceCharacters = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s")).mapToInt(String::length).sum();
```

**OR** Recombine the values without whitespace and grab the length of that:

```
int totalNonWhitespaceCharacters = String.join("", text.split("\\s")).length();
```

**OR** Just directly replace the whitespace character with nothing:

```
int totalNonWhitespaceCharacters = text.replace(" ", "").length();
```

Comment: Actually I used `"\\s"` in my code, but I just curious about how `"\\S"` count.